# Knit in R studio - Error message - File not found in directory

Tags: r, macos, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I just completed a project in RMD and my script wont knit. First I get an error message saying file not in directory.

Then in the render console it as the error message

```
Line 535 Error in check_for_XqQuartz()
X11 library is missing: install XQuartz.macosforge.org
```

The problem is the app won't download on my mac.

Please see three attached screenshots for more information

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want to install `XQuartz` not `X11` (which has been deprecated/discontinued since Panther I think). Is that the issue? XQuartz will provide a current version of the X11 windowing system.

Comment: Hi, I have installed XQuartz on my machine and I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Can you make sure that `XQuartz` is not getting blocked/quarantined by macOS (as a app from an unidentified dev). Also make sure you restart RStudio in a clean session.

Comment: You would find this in the "security and privacy" settings in Mac Setting. What version of XQuartz is installed on the computer? Might have to uninstall and reinstall R/Rstudio/XQuartz as a way of troubleshooting